# Django form & rendering data from model

Tags: django, forms, django-forms, formset

I am currently struggling with Django forms. Based on the tickets model I generate this formset where users can choose the qty of tickets they want. After they will be redirected to the checkout page.

My problem is, when I use {{ form.ticket }} I get a select field but that's not what I'm looking for. I just want to print out the tickets as seen in the screenshot below.

Can anyone help me on that?

How it should be:

[image]

How it currently looks like:

[image]

views.py

```
from django.forms import formset_factory
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render

from .forms import EntryModelForm
from .models import Ticket
from orders.models import Order, Entry

# Create your views here.
def choose_ticket_and_quantity(request):

    tickets = []
    for ticket in Ticket.objects.all():
        tickets.append({'ticket': ticket})

    EntryFormSet = formset_factory(EntryModelForm, extra=0)
    formset = EntryFormSet(initial=tickets)

    if request.POST:
        o = Order.objects.create()
        request.session['order_id'] = o.order_id

        formset = EntryFormSet(request.POST, initial=tickets)

        if formset.is_valid():
            for form in formset:
                if form.cleaned_data['quantity'] > 0:
                    entry = form.save(commit=False)
                    entry.order = o
                    entry.save()

            return redirect('http://127.0.0.1:8000/checkout')

    return render(request, "tickets/choose_ticket_and_quantity.html", {'formset': formset})
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms

from orders.models import Entry

class EntryModelForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model=Entry
        fields = ['ticket', 'quantity']
```

choose_ticket_and_quantity.html

```
<form method="post" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ formset.management_form }}

    {% for form in formset %}
        <ul>
            <li>{{ form.ticket }}</li>
            <li>{{ form.quantity }}</li>
        </ul>

    {% endfor %}

    <p><input type="submit" value="Checkout"></p>
</form>
```

What I also tried was this here, but unfortunately, this didn't work either as my form couldn't be validated anymore and all ticket types have been printed together:

```
{% for choice in form.ticket.field.choices %}
{{choice.1}}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

Add a templatetag `get_ticket.py` in app/templatetags (Add a `__init__.py` too)

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()
# import Ticket model

@register.simple_tag
def get_ticket(pk):
    ticket = Ticket.objects.get(pk=int(pk))
    return ticket.name # is it name?
```

In your template

```
{% load get_ticket %}
<form method="post" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ formset.management_form }}
    <ul>
    {% for form in formset %}
        <li>
            <strong>{% get_ticket form.ticket.value %}</strong><br>
            <input type="hidden" name='{{form.ticket.name}}' value='{{form.ticket.value}}'>
            {{ form.quantity }}
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Checkout"></p>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi @Ramkishore M thank you for the input. The approach with the hidden field is a very good idea. One thing that doesn't work however is that form.ticket.value only gives me back numbers (1 and 2 and 3).

Comment: Hi @Ramkishore M , that's amazing it now shows the ticket name! There is one last issue I have. Once I click on send, I receive the following error message: TypeError at /tickets/cart
int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'

I think the problem lies with the name of the hidden fields? Once I add {{ form.ticket }} the POST request works fine. Do you have any idea?

Example how form.ticket is rendered:
<select name="form-0-ticket" id="id_form-0-ticket">
  <option value="1" selected="">Early Bird Ticket</option>
  [...]
</select>

Comment: One more update: I now removed the hidden field and added {{ form.ticket }} again. After I went into the forms.py and changed the form.ticket widget to HiddenInput() within the def __init__

And this worked! Is this an okay solution? And thanks so much for your help. Now I can finally proceed.

Comment: @JonProgrammer, sure that sounds like the best way to do it. I didn't know about HiddenInput widget. I'll keep that in mind

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to display the value of the field:

```
<li>{{ form.ticket.value }}</li>
```

Comment: Hi Ivan, I tried this as well, but the issue is that I only get numbers back as the value (1 and 2 and 3).

Comment: Is this working? `<li>{{ form.instance.get_ticket_display }}</li>`

Comment: No, unfortunately not. Thank you for trying to help me!

Comment: Do you have any idea why  {{ form.instance.get_ticket_display }} doesn't work here? I read in the documentation about it and it seems like this could be write. However it's not generating any data for me.

Comment: Isn't get_ticket_display for choice field? ticket is foreignkey right?

Comment: @RamkishoreM I think you are right, this field is `ForeignKey` and does not have choices set, this could be a reason why `get_ticket_display` is not working @Jon Programmer.

Comment: Yes exactly, ticket is a foreign key